# How to convert string in JSON to int Swift

Tags: swift

```
self.event?["start"].string
```

The output is = Optional("1423269000000")

I want to get 1423269000000 as an Int

How can we achieve this? I have tried many ways such NSString (but it changed the value)

Answer (score 3):

Your value: `1,423,269,000,000` is bigger than max Int32 value: `2,147,483,647`. This may cause unexpected casting value. For more information, check this out: [Numeric Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html).

Try to run this code:

```
let maxIntegerValue = Int.max
println("Max integer value is: \(maxIntegerValue)")
```

In iPhone 4S simulator, the console output is:

```
Max integer value is: 2147483647
```

And iPhone 6 simulator, the console output is:

```
Max integer value is: 9223372036854775807
```

This information may help you.

But normally to convert Int to String:

```
let mInt : Int = 123
var mString = String(mInt)
```

And convert String to Int:

```
let mString : String = "123"
let mInt : Int? = mString.toInt()

if (mInt != null) {
    // converted String to Int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my safe way to do this using Optional Binding:**

```
var json : [String:String];
json = ["key":"123"];


if var integerJson = json["key"]!.toInt(){
    println("Integer conversion successful : \(integerJson)")
}
else{
    println("Integer conversion failed")
}
```

**Output:**
             `Integer conversion successful :123`

So this way one can be sure if the **conversion** was **successful** or **not**, using `Optional Binding`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, but say you have a dictionary (Where it was JSON or not) You can do this:

```
var dict: [String : String]
dict = ["key1" : "123"]

var x : Int
x = dict["key1"].toInt()
println(x)
```

Comment: old Swift. No longer works. Thanks though for posting.

Comment: @BennyTheNerd So you are downvoting a 2.5 years old questions because it is "old swift"? Be my guest..

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone's still looking for an updated answer, here's the Swift 5+ version:

```
let jsonDict = ["key": "123"];
// Validation
guard let value = Int(jsonDict["key"]) else {
    print("Error! Unexpected value.")
    return
}
print("Integer conversion successful: \(value)")
```

// Prints "Integer conversion successful: 123"